# How to limit the textview text height with 10 lines and then remaining text to scroll in Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitextview

Here I have designed textview which will move up with keyboard and adjust its height depend on the text, in the textview there is no scrolling for textview, now I need textview  should limit with 10 lines then want scrolling.

Below is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var msgTextViewheightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var msgTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewBottomLayoutContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    var activeTextView: UITextView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        msgTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        msgTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
        msgTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        msgTextView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.setupTextView()
        self.registerForKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    func registerForKeyboardNotifications(){
        //Adding notifies on keyboard appearing
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }
    func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications(){
        //Removing notifies on keyboard appearing
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            self.textViewBottomLayoutContraint.constant = keyboardSize.size.height + 10

        }
    }

    func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            self.textViewBottomLayoutContraint.constant = 10

        }
    }

    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {

        activeTextView = textView

    }
    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        activeTextView = nil

    }
    private func textViewShouldReturn(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func setupTextView() {
        if let txtView = msgTextView {

            txtView.scrollsToTop = true
            txtView.isScrollEnabled = true

            txtView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options:[ NSKeyValueObservingOptions.old , NSKeyValueObservingOptions.new], context: nil)
        }
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {

        if let changeDict = change, let constraint = msgTextViewheightConstraint, let view = self.msgTextView {
            if object as? NSObject == self.msgTextView && keyPath == "contentSize" {
                if let oldContentSize = (changeDict[NSKeyValueChangeKey.oldKey] as AnyObject).cgSizeValue,
                    let newContentSize = (changeDict[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as AnyObject).cgSizeValue {

                    let dy = newContentSize.height - oldContentSize.height
                    constraint.constant = constraint.constant + dy;
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    let contentOffsetToShowLastLine = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: view.contentSize.height - view.bounds.height)
                    view.contentOffset = contentOffsetToShowLastLine
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

Please help me in this concept.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of lines of text by dividing the hight of the `textView`'s content by the `textView`'s font's line hight:

```
let numberOfLines = textView.contentSize.height/(textView.font?.lineHeight)!
```

You can then get the size of each line by dividing the `textView.contentSize` by the number of lines it contains:

```
let lineHeight = textView.contentSize.height / numberOfLines
```

Then, in your `viewDidAppear` method, you can set the height constraint for the `textView` to the `lineHeight` times 10:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    textView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: lineHeight * 10)
])
```

Make sure that you are not setting a height constraint in your storyboard  if you do this.